# Signature issue SAML2p Kentor

Tags: asp.net, saml-2.0

I have my SAML2 enpoint in Azure and tried to integrate with Kentor Sample Mvc application. Everything went fine, Even I can see the SAMLRESPONSE with claims(attributes) in it. But I am getting a certificate error like "The signature verified correctly with the key contained in the signature, but that key is not trusted.' occurred in Kentor.AuthServices.dll" . Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: if(signedXml.CheckSignature(key))
                    {
                        ValidateCertificate(validateCertificate, keyIdentifier);
                        return;
                    } --- This line of code is not working, always returning false  for CheckSignature()

Comment: Also came to realize that, signedXml.CheckSignature is returning false always. I dont have a signingcertificate for this Azure SAML2 endpoint ? What to do? or Where from Azure AD , I will get the Cert?

Answer (score 2):

This means that you've configured the wrong signing key with **AuthServices**. Since you're using Azure you should be aware that they roll over (*i.e. change*) keys regularly so you can't just configure the key. You have to configure **AuthServices** to load the Azure metadata automatically. Set the `MetadataLocation` property of the `IdentityProvider` to the metadata address of your Azure tenant.